# Fast way to iterate over rows and return column names where cells meet threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with numic values.  How can I iterate over the rows and return the column name where the cell values meet a threshold (in this case let's say .05)?

The pandas dataframe is 10K rows and 700 columns.  Ideally, I'd want a dictionary returned as seen below.

### MWE

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0,10,size=(8, 7))/100, 
    columns=list('ABCDEFG'), 
    index = ['Dog', "Cat", 'Pig', 'Horse', 'Fish', 'Chicken', 'Squid', 'Cheetah']
)
```

### Yielding

```
   A     B     C     D     E     F     G
----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----  ----
0.05  0     0.03  0.03  0.07  0.09  0.03
0.05  0.02  0.04  0.07  0.06  0.08  0.08
0.01  0.06  0.07  0.07  0.08  0.01  0.05
0.09  0.08  0.09  0.04  0.03  0     0.03
0.05  0     0.02  0.03  0.08  0.01  0.03
0.03  0.03  0.07  0     0.01  0.09  0.09
0     0.04  0.07  0.03  0.02  0.07  0.02
0     0     0.04  0.05  0.05  0.06  0.08
```

### Desired output

```
{
   'Dog': ['A', 'E', 'F'], 
    "Cat": ['A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 
    'Pig': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G'], 
    'Horse': ['A', "B", 'C'], 
    'Fish': ['A', 'E'], 
    'Chicken': ['C', 'F', 'G'], 
    'Squid': ['C', 'F'], 
    'Cheetah': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dict comprehension here with boolean indexing.

```
m = df.ge(0.05).values
out = {k: df.columns[m[i]].tolist() for i, k in enumerate(df.index)}

{'Dog': ['A', 'E', 'F'],
 'Cat': ['A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
 'Pig': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G'],
 'Horse': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 'Fish': ['A', 'E'],
 'Chicken': ['C', 'F', 'G'],
 'Squid': ['C', 'F'],
 'Cheetah': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']}
```

Timeit results:
Benchmarking setup

```
np.random.seed(0)
vals = np.random.rand(10_000, 700)
df_bench = pd.DataFrame(vals)
df_bench.columns = df_bench.columns.astype(str)
```

Output:

```
# @anky's answer
In [49]: %timeit df_bench.ge(thresh).dot(df_bench.columns+',').str.rstrip(",").s
    ...: tr.split(",").to_dict()                                                
1.36 s ± 50.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# @My answer
In [50]: %%timeit 
    ...: m = df_bench.ge(0.05).values 
    ...: out = {k: df_bench.columns[m[i]].tolist() for i, k in enumerate(df_benc
    ...: h.index)} 
    ...:  
    ...:                                                                        
167 ms ± 3.27 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# @Amit's answer
In [51]: %timeit df_bench.apply(lambda x: list(x[x>=0.05].index), axis = 1).to_d
    ...: ict()                                                                  

4.08 s ± 2.31 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

<sup>Tested for equality all solutions give the same output.</sup>

Comment: **Unique** (: Nice one

Comment: @anky Thank you. :) Solution looks much better than mine :)

Comment: **Excellent!** So plain dict comprehension works much better. `.apply` is usually so bad that I just don't want to see my answer.

Comment: In the @anky answer, the `.str` is the bottleneck. I happened to use `.str` in one of my project and found that list comprehension works faster than that.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh That may not be the case always though but in general `df.apply` over axis 1 is avoided. `df.apply` over axis 0 is better than axis 1. I guess my solution is faster since it only uses boolean indexing which is a very fast and simple operation and `df.ge` is vectorized operation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Usually operation along axis 0 can be done by referring the columns itself so I never happened to use `.apply` for axis = 0. For axis = 1, I have found that `list comprehension`  works faster in most of the cases.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh simply put if your code is readable as well as fast. Don't care. Priority readability, second speed if it's not killing you

Comment: @anky Couldn't agree more.

Comment: Wow very fast.  Thanks for the additional benchmarking too!

Comment: Also my first encounter with `enumerate()`...pretty terrific!

Answer (score 3):

this can be achieved by a **[`dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html)** product:

```
thresh = .05
df.ge(thresh).dot(df.columns+',').str.rstrip(",").str.split(",").to_dict()
```

---

```
{'Dog': ['A', 'E', 'F'],
 'Cat': ['A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
 'Pig': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G'],
 'Horse': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 'Fish': ['A', 'E'],
 'Chicken': ['C', 'F', 'G'],
 'Squid': ['C', 'F'],
 'Cheetah': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']}
```

Comment: Both excellent answers.  This one was faster for my use case +1

Comment: @anky Added timeit results. I guess the bottleneck in this solution is `.str` functions I guess they are not vectorized. To my surprise, plain dict comprehension was faster. `.dot` is really cleverly used. ;)

Comment: Well str is vectorized but since string funcs are slow and build on top of str python,they are just slower than vanilla. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
output = df.apply(lambda x: list(x[x>=0.05].index), axis = 1).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'Dog': ['A', 'E', 'F'], 
'Cat': ['A', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'], 
'Pig': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'G'], 
'Horse': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
'Fish': ['A', 'E'], 
'Chicken': ['C', 'F', 'G'], 
'Squid': ['C', 'F'], 
'Cheetah': ['D', 'E', 'F', 'G']}
```

Comment: Both excellent answers.  The dot product one was faster for my use case +1

Comment: Yes. Pandas apply is usually slow.